# Python - Importing 2 classes into main file

Tags: python, class

I not very sure how to phrase the question subject...

I have 3 files laid out:

**bank.py:**

```
class Bank(object):

    def __init__(self, money):
        self.money = money

    def currentMoney(self):
        print "You currently have $%d" %self.money

    def useMoney(self, money_use):
        self.money = self.money - money_use
        print "You used $%d" %money_use
        self.currentMoney()

    def getMoney(self, money_get):
        self.money = self.money + money_get
        print "You received $%d" %money_get
        self.currentMoney()
```

**event.py:**

```
class Event(object):

    def Event1(self):
        print "Your dad needs money. Will you give him?"
        decision = raw_input("Yes or No")
        if decision == "Yes":
            Bank.useMoney(500)
        elif decision == "No":
            print "Your father is sad"
        else:
            print "I do not know what are you talking about"
```

**main.py:**

```
import bank
import event

Bank = bank.Bank(1000)
Event = event.Event()

Event.Event1()
```

When I execute the code. I get the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'Bank' is not defined
```

Basically, what I would like to do is to use event.py to create a series of events that will affect the money, and I can use main.py to run different series of events.

Would you be able to enlighten me how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Don't use the same names in main.py for the variables you are assigning the instances of the objects to as you do for their classes or modules.  Should be `bank1 = bank.Bank(1000)`, `event1 = event.Event()`, etc.

Comment: Sigh. Python is not Java. 1. You can have more that one class per file; 2. There's no need for classes if you're not encapsulating any data: Event has no need to be a class.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, you need to import `Bank` in `event.py`

```
from bank import Bank
```

Having said that, looking at the code in `event.py`, you're going to run into another error on the line:

```
 Bank.useMoney(500)
```

As `useMoney()` takes `self` as the first argument, so it needs to be run on a `Bank` **instance** rather than on the class itself (in Java-type speak, `useMoney` is an instance method, not a static method).

I *think* what your intent is is to have a `Bank` instance be contained inside `Event`, and then call `useMoney` on that whenever `Event1` is called.

Comment: Hi Adam, could you recommend me a way to structure the class so that I can do what I intended to do? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks! I think this is possible. The reason why I split it out is so that I can use the Bank in other way later on. For example, I could have a shop.py, that I can useMoney to buyStuff.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `import bank` in `event.py`, and use

```
if decision == "Yes":
    bank.Bank(...)
```

or you could use at the beginning of your `event.py`:

```
from bank import Bank

class Event(object):
    ...
```

Otherwise, Python cannot know that the `Bank` object is defined in the `bank` module when it loads the `event` module.